# Find all combinations with repetitions but without duplicate rows

Tags: java, algorithm

There is an array of 1, 2, 3, 4. It is necessary to make all possible combinations of 3 size series, the elements can be repeated. The order of the elements in the row is not important. For instance:
114 = 411 = 141.
I can't find a suitable algorithm. I have found this algorithm, but there can be no repetitions of elements, like 111 or 113, only 123,124 etc.

```
public void doit(){
String[] arr = {"1", "2", "3","4"};
            int count = fuctorial(arr.length);
            int max = arr.length - 1;
            System.out.println("Вариантов " + count);
            int shift = max;
            String t;
            while (count > 0) {
                t = arr[shift];
                arr[shift] = arr[shift - 1];
                arr[shift - 1] = t;
                print(arr);
                count--;
                if (shift < 2) {
                    shift = max;
                } else {
                    shift--;
                }
            }
}
    static void print(String[] arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
 
    static int fuctorial(int n) {
        return (n > 0) ? n * fuctorial(n - 1) : 1;
    }
```

Comment: 114 is ok but why 113 not ok?

Comment: @deadshot They are both ok. But if we have 311 and 113, they are the same. So we don't need 113.

Comment: So when you say no repetition of elements, do you mean no repetition of consequent elements ie: 113 is not allowed, 122 is not allowed but 121 is allowed? @МикитаМостоцький

Comment: @manzk I'm sorry for my English. I mean that I need to find unique combinationts. for example: we have 111,112,113,114 and then 121 is not unique alreade. Because 112 = 121. Next possible combination is 122

Comment: @МикитаМостоцький oh so i think i got what you mean. you do not want sets which contain the same elements because they are the same set right? so 132 = 123

Comment: @manzk yep, you understood me correctly

Comment: @МикитаМостоцький I have added an answer. Might not be the most time efficient one but this will work for your case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
static void combination(int[] a, int n) {
    int size = a.length;
    int[] selected = new int[n];
    new Object() {

        void print() {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                System.out.print(a[selected[i]] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }

        void combination(int index, int prev) {
            if (index >= n)
                print();
            else
                for (int i = prev; i < size; ++i)
                    combination(index + 1, selected[index] = i);
        }

    }.combination(0, 0);
}
```

and

```
int[] a = {6, 7, 8, 9};
combination(a, 3);
```

output:

```
6 6 6 
6 6 7 
6 6 8 
6 6 9 
6 7 7 
6 7 8 
6 7 9 
6 8 8 
6 8 9 
6 9 9 
7 7 7 
7 7 8 
7 7 9 
7 8 8 
7 8 9 
7 9 9 
8 8 8 
8 8 9 
8 9 9 
9 9 9
```

Comment: But this includes `6 6 6` and `6 6 7`, even though the question states that there must be no repetition in the sequences? So the output should be `6 7 8; 6 7 9; 6 8 9; 7 8 9` only?

Comment: No that is ok. Read the description. I have some troubles in English so maybe you understood me wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
public void func() {
    boolean[] check = new boolean[49];
    for(int i=1; i <=4; i++ ) {
        for(int j=1; j <=4; j++) {
            for(int k=1; k<=4; k++) {
                int sum = i*i + j*j + k*k;
                if(!check[sum]) {
                    check[sum] = true;
                    System.out.println(i + "," + j + "," + k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

idea is: we take a triplet, calculate the sum of squares, and check if we already had a triplet with that sum. identical triplets will have the same sum of squares.
the sum of squares will always be in the range 3-48. also, the sum is unique to each combination of numbers just like you require.

Complexity is O(N^3) where N is the size of the array. since we need combinations of 3 elements, i don't think you can go below that.

**UPDATE:** to make is more general, use a HashSet for the sums instead of the boolean array, and iterate 3 nested loops over the input array. calculate the sum of squares and check against the HashSet.

Performance Optimization: calculate the squares of each element in the array in advance so you dont have to calculate them over and over again.

Comment: Checking the sum will not work because what if you have [123] & [222]

Comment: sum of SQUARES. 1+4+9 = 14, 4+4+4=12

Comment: It is an example with elements. The array can contain more than 4 elements and with different values. That is, this is a little not what I need